# Store cookie from HTTP header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do you store a cookie with basic info.

i.e. link is http://www.domain.com/index.html?ref=123

How would I store a cookie with name of "ref" and the value of "123"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Cookies.html

use following code in your controller:

```
cookies[:ref] = 123
```

or

```
cookies[:ref] = params[:ref]
```